# Generate a subset of list in a cyclical manner

Tags: python-3.x, list, rotation

`x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.
`y = 3`. Assume `y<=len(x)`

How do I generate subsets from `x` of length `y` such as

```
[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,1] ....
```

Assuming that the first subset is `x[:3]`, how do I keep generating the rest of the subsets?

EDIT 1: My solution based on @Jordan's answer

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = 3

sublist = None

def cycles(xs, y, prev):
    start = 0 if prev[-1]==xs[-1] else (xs.index(prev[-1])+1)
    sublist = [xs[i % len(xs)] for i in range(start, start + y)]
    start = (start + y) % len(xs)
    return sublist

for _ in range(10):

    if sublist == None:
        prev = xs[0:y]
        prev = cycles(xs, y, prev)
        print("first")
        sublist = prev
    else:
        prev = cycles(xs, y, prev)


    print(prev)
```

Comment: Are you looking for combinations of x taken 3 at a time?

Comment: @itprorh66 but in the same forward sequence as shown in the example.

Comment: I think @Jordan has provided your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep generating them using a generator. One possible solution (which also works for `y > len(x)`):

```py
def cycles(xs, y):
    start = 0
    while True:
        sublist = [xs[i % len(xs)] for i in range(start, start + y)]
        start = (start + y) % len(xs)
        yield sublist
```

Comment: I was looking for something that can generate the next subset given the current one. e.g. if the input is `[4,5,6]`, the result is `[7,1,2]`